# Problem loading Windows over Ubuntu - not reading boot usb on reboot

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I'm new to Ubuntu, I had been wanting to try it for a while. My hard drive on my HP Envy m6 crashed, so I had to get a new one outside of warranty. I didn't want to pay for windows discs, so I decided to go with the free Ubuntu. I've had nothing but problems due to incompatibility with the HP components.. wifi works at 10% normal. After many frustrations with Wine not working at all, and not being code savvy, I've decided to rid myself of Ubunut. 
I've got a working usb boot drive with Win7 on it.
When I reboot my machine with USB drive at the top of the boot options in BIOS, screen flashes once then goes blank with no hard drive activity.
I am still able to run Ubuntu, as well as boot from the Ubuntu USB I created. Yet nothing from the Win7 stick.
The hard drive was brand new, and I was only able to load Ubuntu with a flash drive of less than 2gb due to no drivers being loaded on HD yet.
Why am I unable to boot from the Win7 NTFS stick?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you made the bootstick, make sure you had it flagged for boot.

If you just dragged 'n dropped the files over, it's likely the cause.

I'd use brasero, it should do it for you, that or use disk utility in Ubuntu.